# Apache as forward proxy with SSL passthrough

Tags: apache, proxy, aix

I am trying to setup apache as forward proxy and to allow SSL passthrough also.

Will the below configuration work? I am not sure if SSL passthrough is enabled by default for apache as forward proxy.

```
# Proxy Server directives. Uncomment the following lines to
# enable the proxy server:
#
#<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

#Enable the forward proxy server. Note: Do not use the ProxyRequests         directive if
#all you require is reverse proxy.
#
ProxyRequests On
AllowCONNECT 80 443 49171
#
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

Allow from 10.241.152.26

</Proxy>

#    Allow from .example.com

#
# Enable/disable the handling of HTTP/1.1 "Via:" headers.
# ("Full" adds the server version; "Block" removes all outgoing Via: headers)
# Set to one of: Off | On | Full | Block
#
#ProxyVia On

#</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AllowCONNECT` should be more than enough for anyone still interested.